# How to find latest documents from mongoDB if they have the equals time

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to download from mongodb latest documents - documents if they have the same timestamp in mongoDB.
Is there any way to found the latest document or documents?

So in this example, the returned document should be the first one and the second one.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fbf852902fe571c41d07c9f"),
    "insertionTime" : ISODate("2020-11-26T10:36:25.600Z")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fbf852902fe571c41d07ca0"),
    "insertionTime" : ISODate("2020-11-26T10:36:25.600Z")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fbf852902fe571c41d07ca1"),
    "insertionTime" : ISODate("2020-11-24T10:36:25.600Z")
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fbf854702fe571c41d07ca9"),
    "insertionTime" : ISODate("2020-11-23T10:36:55.582Z")
}
```

I was able to found out only the latest document but only by the limit.

```
private List<Bson> prepareFilter() {
    Bson sortByTimeFilter = sort(Sorts.descending(INSERTION_TIME));
    Bson latestFilter = limit(1);
    return Arrays.asList(sortByTimeFilter, latestFilter);
}
```

After trying to aggregate collection I have received the only one document. Of course, thanks to the limit(1) are only one document. Is there any way to aggregate N latest document if they have the same timestamp?

Thanks in advance.
Best Regards

Comment: Does the answer help you?

Comment: @varman I am sorry for not answering before, I just saw your comment. No. It didin't help me, because I couldn''t use MongoTemplate :(.

Answer (score 0):

I use MongoTemplate to do the aggregation. I tell a way here. Autowire the MongoTemplate

@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

- `$sort` helps to sort by insertionTime
- `$group` helps to find the latest object `latestDoc` and meanwhile push all document to array `allDocs`
- Since we have the latest document and all document array, we can filter the all document array using latest document timestamp,
- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array (now `allDocs` array becomes object)
- `$replaceRoot` to replace the object to ROOT

The method is

```
public List<Object> test(List<String> companies,List<String> professions ) {

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "insertionTime"),
        group()
            .first("$$ROOT").as("latestDoc")
            .push("$$ROOT").as("allDocs")
        p-> new Document("$project",
                new Document("allDocs",                     
                    new Document("$filter"
                        new Document()
                        .append("input","$allDocs")                     
                        .append("cond",
                            new Document("$eq",Arrays.asList("$$this.insertionTime","$latestDoc.insertionTime"))
                        )
                    )
                                                            
            )
        ),
        unwind("allDocs"),
        replaceRoot("allDocs")

    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(YOUR_COLLECTION.class), Object.class).getMappedResults();

}
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9qOQk_zKUKb)**

If you dont use Mongo template, you can use as you already tried or [TRICK TO CONVERT MONGO SHELL](http://pingax.com/trick-convert-mongo-shell-query-equivalent-java-objects/)

Note : This code is not tested. But it was written on working above mongo script